# Marshal C++ float to C# float accuracy problem

Tags: c#, c++, floating-point, dbase

I have a DBase IV database. Each row has a memo field with a ASCII encoded string that holds two serialized borland c++ structures.  I am able to pull the data using OleDb, re-encode it to ascii using the ASCIIEncoding class, convert it to bytes using a BinaryReader, and cast it to my C# struct using Marshal.PtrToStructure.  The data I get is correct but any float that is to big in the database is completely wrong when it is cast to the c#.  For example, a value of 1149.00 cast  into 764.9844 but a value like 64.00 cast fine.  I can post some of the code and the structures but I figured I tried to keep it short at first.  I know that floats are only precise up to 7 digits but I'm confused why I'm seeing this because the values are under that limit.

Edit:

```
struct cplusplusstruct // from the c++ code
{
  int   Number;
  float P;
  float ZP;
  float Hours;
  int   Month;
  int   Day;
  int   Year;
  int   Hour;
  int   Minute;
  int   Second;
  ULONG UPCTime;
  int   B;
  char  Name[21];
  float L;
  float H;
  float S;
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct csharpstruct  //The C# struct I created
{
     public int Number;
     public float Pr;
     public float ZP;
     public float Hours;
     public int Month;
     public int Day;
     public int Year;
     public int Hour;
     public int Minute;
     public int Second;
     public UInt32 UPCTime;
     public int B;
 [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 21)]
     public string Name;
     public float L;
     public float H;
     public float S;
 }


//OLE DB Connection and query ...

//Casting data to struct
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] blob = encoding.GetBytes(memoString);
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(blob);
BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);

int dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(csharpstruct));
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(binaryReader.ReadBytes(dataSize), GCHandleType.Pinned);
csharpstruct data = (csharpstruct) Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(csharpstruct));
```

Edit: The following is java code that read the data just fine but without any use of casting.

```
org.xBaseJ.DBF dbf = new org.xBaseJ.DBF(dbPath);
org.xBaseJ.DBF dbf = new org.xBaseJ.DBF(dbPath);
MemoField m = (MemoField) dbf.getField("MEMOFIELD");

Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
ByteBuffer trendBytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(m.getBytes());
trendBytes.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
trendBytes.getInt();
trendBytes.getFloat();
```

Comment: Care to post some code snippets?

Comment: Is the C++ structure a double or is it compiled to use a different floating point model?

Comment: @Sparkie - If it would help I will

Comment: @plinth - the data type in the c++ struct is a float.  I'm unsure of the floating point model but it was compiled using an older version of Borland C++ compiler.

Comment: "re-encode to ascii" is no doubt the fatal step.  Comparing byte values before and after each step brings insight.

Comment: The data is saved to the database as ascii.  Without re-encode to ascii I get a bunch of gibberish.

Comment: What does "ASCII encoded string" mean? Can you share an example of how a float is encoded in ASCII?

Comment: These assumptions where gathered from a java application that was written to read the data.  I added the code that does the following and works perfect to the original post.  Also, the legacy code reads the DB into a character array and the casts it to the struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve the issue directly.  The problem seemed to come from the OLE data provider I was using. The data retreived from the database was slightly different then what [xBaseJ](http://xbasej.sourceforge.net/) provided.  I ended up converting xBaseJ to CLI bytecode using [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/).  This allowed me to replace the OLE data provider with the xBaseJ reader.  The rest of my code remained unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

You have `Pack = 1` in your C# struct, but have not said whether your C++ struct is packed. Since you have an odd-sized field just before your floats (the 21-character string) that might cause trouble and mean that your floats are being read mis-aligned. Everything before there is 4 bytes long so packing is less likely to cause you problems. I would make sure that the packing matches in both C# and C++ before going any further.

Comment: The C++ header specifies #pragma pack(1).

Comment: Also note that this issue occurs on all the floats in the struct.  If the value is in the 1000's it gets messed up.  If not, then I get the correct data.